# Zend Framework MultiCheckbox and Routing

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, url

Zend Framework doesn't seem to support multi-checkboxes in its URL router. If I submit a multi-checkbox form, the values come up in the controller as an array, but if I then pass those directly to the router, it chokes

This is the multi-checkbox array from `Controller->getRequest()->getParams()`:

```
[make] => Array
    (
        [0] => Honda
        [1] => Toyota
        [2] => Subaru
    )
```

If I send that array to `$this->url` in either the Controller or the view, this happens:

```
Warning: urlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in Zend/Controller/Router/Route.php on line 403
```

I really want to avoid having to rebuild the URL myself, but I'm not sure how to get the router to process multi-dimensional params.

Comment: How are you trying to use this array? What are your expectations? $this->url() is looking for an array like array('controller'=> 'name', 'action'=> 'name', array(params)). You can send an array to params but controller action and module need to be string.

Comment: I am simply trying to pass it to `$this->url()`. The params come down from the Controller formatted as multi-dimensional arrays but the router cannot parse the params as multi-dimensional arrays. This seems like a design flaw or contradiction in Zend Framework.

Comment: it's not a design flaw, you have just exceeded the intent of the view helper. Your best bet would be to build you own view helper.